# Remove parent div in product grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

Firstly I want to apologize for my English. I have a html template for shop and it has interesting structure of product grid in category page:

HTML:

```
    <div class="product-line">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-line">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-small"></div>
            <div class="product-big"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-center .product-line {
  position: relative;
  height: 238px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.content-center .product-line .product {
  position: absolute;
  color: #534741;
}
.content-center .product:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.content-center .product:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 330px;
}
.content-center .product:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 660px;
}
.content-center .product-small {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 238px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #dbdbdb;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.content-center .product-big {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 630px;
  min-height: 506px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #dbdbdb;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.detail').on('click', function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var parentProduct = _this.closest('.product');
        var parentLine = _this.closest('.product-line');
        var index = parentProduct.index();

        var eq1 = parentLine.find('.product').eq(0);
        var eq2 = parentLine.find('.product').eq(1);
        var eq3 = parentLine.find('.product').eq(2);


        $('.product-small').show();
        $('.product-big').hide();
        $('.product-line').css('height', '237px');
        $('.product').removeAttr('style');


        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                eq1.css({'left' : 0, 'top' : 0});
                eq2.css({'left' : '660px', 'top' : 0});
                eq3.css({'left' : '660px', 'top' : '268px'});
            break;

            case 1:
                eq1.css({'left' : 0, 'top' : 0});
                eq2.css({'left' : '330px', 'top' : 0});
                eq3.css({'left' : 0, 'top' : '268px'});
            break;

            case 2:
                eq1.css({'left' : 0, 'top' : 0});
                eq2.css({'left' : 0, 'top' : '268px'});
                eq3.css({'left' : '330px', 'top' : 0});
            break;
        }

        parentProduct.find('.product-big').show();
        parentProduct.find('.product-small').hide();
        parentLine.css('height', parentProduct.find('.product-big').innerHeight());

    });
```

Is it possible to make same functional but use only one block where products stored.
Now I have a lot of blocks where stored 3 products(x lines per 3 products), and I need to make only one block and unlimited products. For example make something like that:

```
 <div class="product-line">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-small"></div>
        <div class="product-big"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-small"></div>
        <div class="product-big"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-small"></div>
        <div class="product-big"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-small"></div>
        <div class="product-big"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-small"></div>
        <div class="product-big"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'm tried to use `float:left` method, but when i click "detail" button the grid is braking.
Site with current functional: [link](http://sushipood.eu/category.html)

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is,, The link you shared seems to be working fine. The grid doesnt break at all

Comment: Working fine for me too in Chrome.

Comment: What he has is working, but in his html he has a <div class="product-line"> for each row, and he explicitly lists three products in each product line. He wants to be able to achieve the same functionality he already has working at that link, but without having to have all those <div class="product-line">. He only wants one of those and then all of the products go in there. I'm not sure of the reason. Maybe he wants it to wrap on its own.

Comment: @goodface87 Exactly. Reason is that I want to use this template with  ecommerce cms (for example opencart) and this cms does not separate products by div. It has only one div where are all products

Comment: Do you really need the absolute positioning? If I take your HTML, throw out all the CSS, and apply a simple float to the `product` divs while leaving the `product-line` divs alone, I get more or less what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yhwu9zh7/1/ Unless you have additional demands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, use `float`, but `float:right` every 2nd and 3rd items
selected product should have a class 'selected';
don't use `style` attribute (always important to separate style and content)

```
.product { float: left; }
.product.selected:nth-child(3n),
.product.selected:nth-child(3n+2) { float: right; }
.product.product-small { display: block; }
.product.selected .product-small { display: none; }
.product.product-big{ display: none; }
.product.selected .product-big{ display: block; }
```

you'll probably have problems that now `#content-main` is considered empty, but I believe you'll be able to manage that (try `clear:both`).